# Supplying and measuring from current transformer

Tags: power-supply, ac, measurement, current-transformer

I need to provide supply voltage to take measurements and also get measured signal from same current transformer, which will be placed on AC line. Current transformer parameters, such as internal inductance and internal resistance are known. Upper voltage limit from current transformer 48 V. The problem is that I cannot create a circuit in which the input signal will not be distorted (in terms of frequency) when part of power is taken from the measured signal. Are there any possibilities to do so?

Comment: A current transformer won't be happy when the burden is too low or too high.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a power supply from current transformer (I2 in simulation), with low power losses. The SCR will switch on when Voltage is over zener D3, C6 is charged at this voltage - D2 voltage drop, and negative wave is bypassed by D1.

U4 is a 5 V regulator, maximum current cannot be >100 mA, which is the minimum current to be measured.

V shunt will be 100mV @ 1 A , op-amp (rail to rail) U3 will shift the measured value to Vcc/2=2.5 V, R9/R10 will reduce signal to the half and will be increased with a gain=11 by R11/R12.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You need to provide the range of currents you will be measuring, and the corresponding output you have available. It should be possible to design a circuit that will alternately use the output to charge a large capacitor or battery, and then use minimal loading techniques to perform the measurements required.

(edit)

Knowing now that the range of output will be 100mA to 1A, and a maximum voltage (burden) of 40V, it might be best to use a 1 ohm 2W resistor on the output, which will provide a voltage of 100mV-1V, and also a [1:16.67 CT](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/triad-magnetics/CSE184L/5970093) that can provide 5.9 to 59 mA through a bridge rectifier and recommended burden load of 60 ohms.

This should be enough to provide at least 3.3 VDC to power a microcontroller and other measuring devices, with a total power of about 20 mW. This circuit would be isolated from the 1 ohm sense resistor, so its voltage (100 mV - 1 V) could be measured directly and processed as desired. The power supply should incorporate a capacitor (or rechargeable battery) large enough to ride through any possible low current brownout conditions.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Currents on line will vary from 0A to 1kA, currents from CT up to 1A. If i understood "corresponding output you have available" right, i have actually undetermined AC signal with main harmonic of 50Hz and lots of parasitic due to inductive load on that AC line (later measured signal will be filtered with cutoff frequency of 1kHz on MCU).

Comment: It obviously can't work with 0A. So one needs to know the minimum current and corresponding output. Can it be battery powered?

Comment: Yeah, i understand it. The lowest current which should be sensed in line is 100A, which corresponds to 100mA runnig through CT.

Comment: And it can't be battery powered

Comment: It means that i should ground one of the inputs of CT, which placed on AC line, put on it's output 1W resistor and supply net, isolated with another transformer from input of CT, or i am missing something?

Answer (score 1):

You may be able to use a nonlinear load (think of something like a bipolar shunt regulator) dropping a voltage well within the maximum rated burden of the CT and still get a pure enough current through an additional resistor.

Then you can tap off, rectify, filter and regulate power for your circuit, and still have a signal across the sense resistor to measure.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Never saw shut regulator which will be for bipolar use, can you provide links or any other information on it?

Comment: Think of two back to back power Zeners, or a circuit that does something similar.